# Buggy comment highlighting in election page

Tags: bug, comments, design, election

This blog post: [New Question Asker Features](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/08/new-question-asker-features/), explain that **system will highlight comment responses from the user who asked the question**. **YES**, it is currently working fine in all sites. So, I presume this system also works in Stack Overflow election page i.e. *the system should  highlight the comment from the candidate*.

Unfortunately, the system looks buggy in [election page of Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/election?cb=1) and [Role-Playing-Games SE](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/election?cb=1).

When you load the page for the first time, the candidate comments weren't highligted.

> [image: before "show more comment" clicked]

But if you click the **Show xx more comments**, the system magically highlight the candidate comments.

> [image: after"show more comment" clicked]

---

Reproduced in Firefox 37.01 and Chrome  41.0.2272.118 of Windows 7.